# Cannot launch startup disk creator

Tags: startup-disk-creator

Error message:
`An unhandled exception occurred: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: Invalid start byte`

I tried reinstalling usb-creator-gtk, that did not work.
I tried restarting my machine, that didn't work.
I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Gnome-Disks will do the same thing as SDC. Open Disks, select Restore Disk Image from the upper right three dot icon and then select the ISO as Image to Restore.

Comment: If you don't have Gnome disks, install it using `sudo apt install usb-creator-gtk`.